# Navbar js and other bootstrap elements do not wor

Tags: javascript

I'm doing something wrong and I don't know what. I can't seem to get the bootstrap js elements to work. I think it's because of the position that I put the calls to the scripts because it happened to me before but I don't remember what I had wrong.

Head:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Before the closing tag of body:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    <script src="js/rules.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is the complete code, in case you are in the middle of the problem.
FULL HTML:

```
<?php
    require "config.php";
    require "conexion.php";
    
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Useful websites. The best websites with online utilities</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Useful websites</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a id="rulesButton" class="nav-link" href="#">Rules</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Submit web</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div id="rules">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum ipsa alias, iure voluptates voluptate dicta natus blanditiis iste non nemo, autem sit mollitia maxime laudantium necessitatibus reprehenderit ea enim? Suscipit! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia libero saepe voluptas, voluptatum quia totam pariatur impedit amet repellat iste, ducimus omnis fuga quasi unde. A hic harum sed quasi!</p>
        </div>

        <div id="info">
            <p>There are currently <b>157 websites</b> that can be useful to you, do you want to <a href="">add a new website</a> to the list ? Don't forget to <a href="">read the rules</a> before doing so</p>
        </div>

        <!--
        <div id="categories">
            <a href="">All Websites</a><a href="">Documents</a><a href="">Pictures</a><a href="">Video</a><a href="">Learn</a><a href="">Curious</a><a href="">Health</a><a href="">Games</a><a href="">programming</a><a href="">Sound</a><a href="">Informative</a><a href="">Design</a><a href="">Sports</a><a href="">Travel</a><a href="">Kids</a><a href="">Shopping</a>
        </div>
        -->

        <div id="buttons">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Visit random site</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Last</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Best</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Worst</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Random</a>
        </div>

        <div id="ranking">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Description</th>
                        <th scope="col">Visits</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a target="_blank" href="https://www.worldometers.info/watch/world-population/region.php">All People on 1 page</a></td>
                        <td>Displays live world population by region</td>
                        <td class="mx-auto">1345</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a target="_blank" href="https://asoftmurmur.com/">A Sfot Murmur</a></td>
                        <td>Create your own ambient sound to your liking, rain, fire, thunder, birds, air...</td>
                        <td class="mx-auto">997</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a target="_blank" href="https://www.manualslib.com/">ManualsLib</a></td>
                        <td>If you have lost the manual of anything, cell phone, washing machine, television, mp3 player, you can find it here</td>
                        <td class="mx-auto">812</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="mx-auto"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="mx-auto"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="mx-auto"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="mx-auto"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="mx-auto"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="mx-auto"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="mx-auto"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
<script src="js/rules.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This not the reason for the problem but you should have the Bootstrap js and CSS file of the same version.

Comment: Can you share the complete html file!

Answer (score 0):

These two attributes `data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"` of `.navbar-toggler` should be `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"`

```
<button
  class="navbar-toggler"
  type="button"
  data-toggle="collapse"
  data-target="#navbarNav"
  aria-controls="navbarNav"
  aria-expanded="false"
  aria-label="Toggle navigation"
>
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

> Documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/#supported-content